# Two "," splited strings, split each of them for a hashmap's key/value pair

Tags: ruby

I have two strings:

```
str1 = "k1,k2,k3,k4";
str2 = "v1,v2,v3,v4";
```

In Ruby, what's the best way to split each of them, and form a hashmap like:

```
k1 => v1;
k2 => v2;
k3 => v3;
k4 => v4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming the two arrays have the same number of elements you can use a combination of [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
str1 = "k1,k2,k3,k4"
str2 = "v1,v2,v3,v4"

Hash[str1.split(',').zip(str2.split(','))]
# => {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"v2", "k3"=>"v3", "k4"=>"v4"}
```

Note that `;` is only for combining multiple statements on one line and shouldn't be used otherwise.

If you want that formatted as you have it:

```
hash = Hash[str1.split(',').zip(str2.split(','))]

hash.each do |key, value|
  puts '%s => %s;' % [ key, value ]
end
```